# pip virtualenv reset the path after reactivating

Tags: python, path, pip, virtualenv

I have installed pip3 virtualenv and installed couple of packages to it by activating the virtualenv. At that time, the command `which python` gives the path of virtualenv. lets say `..../env/bin/python`

But after deactivate and source the path again (**reactivating**) `which python` uses the global path `/usr/bin/python` which doesn't allow to use the packages I installed to virtualenv. Any thought of that?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work. I don't think you understood how `pip` and isolated environments work.

Comment: Yes, DroidX86 is right, what do you expect? You can only use packages of a virtual env while it is activated.

Comment: I understand how exactly they work. the global `PATH` variable changes after activating. But it still uses the global python path under `/usr/bin`. Maybe you don't understand the question. Read again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake.
the virtualenv maintain a script in directory `..../env/bin` named `activate`
And the file uses absolute path to the `export PATH` and guess what can go wrong.

Let's say the absolute `PATH` is `/home/user/test/env/bin`

And if you rename the directory `test` into `test2`. The activating file still uses old absolute path. So you have to manually change the `PATH` under `.../env/bin/activate` and change the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable to your new absolute path

Answer (score 0):

Normally it does not happen. upon reactivating it should pick from virtualenv python.

My two cents.

1. Virtualenv adding the python in end of PATH variable. so
   usr/bin/python will be in front found n run.
2. It also can happen if your .bash_profile got issues. It may also
   if virtual env is created in python3 and by default it will have
   python2.7

So you need to check both path and both env global vs virtual env one.